# FilteredList setPredicate() only reevaluates once

Tags: javafx-8

I have a FilteredList building a TableView set up according to the example in http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-sorting-filtering/.

The default predicate works fine and when the PropertyChangeListener fires the setPredicate() method is invoked correctly every time but only the FIRST invocation results in the running of the predicate filter code and the subsequent updating of the TableView.

What have I missed here?

```
@Override // This method is called by the FXMLLoader when initialization is complete
public void initialize(URL fxmlFileLocation, ResourceBundle resources) {

.
.
.
    // Wrap the ObservableList in a FilteredList (initially display all data).
    FilteredList<Filedata> filteredData = new FilteredList<>( eeModel.data, p -> true );

    // 2. Set the filter Predicate whenever the filter changes.

    FilterDataClass.addPropertyChangeListener( new PropertyChangeListener()  {

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            System.out.println("PCE...");

            filteredData.setPredicate(fd -> {
                if ( FilterDataClass.getFilenameDupe() == FilterDataClass.FilterStatus.cbIGNORE ) {
                    return true;
                }
                else if ( (FilterDataClass.getFilenameDupe() == FilterDataClass.FilterStatus.cbON) && fd.isFilenameDuplicate() ) {
                    return true;                        
                }
                else if ( (FilterDataClass.getFilenameDupe() == FilterDataClass.FilterStatus.cbOFF) && !fd.isFilenameDuplicate() ) {
                    return true;                        
                }   
                else {
                        return false;                                                               
                }                                       
            });                         
        }
    });


    // Wrap the FilteredList in a SortedList. 
    SortedList<Filedata> sortedList = new SortedList<>( filteredData );

    // create a TableView with the sorted list set as the items it will show
    table.setItems( sortedList );

    // bind the sortedList comparator to the TableView comparator
    sortedList.comparatorProperty().bind(table.comparatorProperty());


}
```

EDIT:

Might this be an optimisation issue?  If I add some junk code to the predicate that requires the evaluation of the event data, such as:

```
                    if ( evt.getNewValue() == evt.getOldValue() ) {
                    System.out.println("This should never happen");
                }
```

then the predicate gets reevaluated.

Comment: can't know without knowing FilterDataClass .. ;-) Also: a) be careful when mixing fx with old style properties (you might run into threading issues) b) please stick to java naming conventions (the addPropertyListener isn't a class method, is it?)

Comment: @kleopatra: Properties are incompatible with FX? Got a reference for that please?

Comment: didn't say they are incompatible - just that they require careful consideration. Please read my comments carefully ..